# Is it possible to hide the title bar or to combine it with the menu bar and/or toolbar

Tags: texstudio

Is it possible to hide the title bar in TexStudio, or to combine it with the menu (and/or tool) bar? I want to do this to save up space as my laptop screen is not that big. I researched it online and looked trough the settings but by the looks of it, it does not appear to be possible.

[image: image displaying the bars in question]

Comment: someone knows how to do the same move on overleaf?

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide the title bar, you can use the built-in full screen mode by pressing `F11` or by going to **View > Full Screen**. However, only hiding the title bar might not make such a big difference. Maybe it is more beneficial to hide toolbars and other panels (e.g. the side panel), because TeXStudio has quite a lot of them and most functionalities are already easily accessible via hotkeys or the menu bar.

Comment: As this does hide the ttitle bar, it also hides the taskbar. I was more thinking about what firefox and microsoft office do for example. In this case that would entail replacing the path name that is displayed, by the menu bar and possible other bars. 
In terms of creating space, I already disabled most of the toolbars and in normal usage I either view or hide the PDF example over the full width.